# How to access a string inside a different function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

How do I access a string that is inside a different function? I need to access myArrayOfLines.

```
public var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;

myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, GameEnter.onLoaded) //GameEnter is the document class
myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("Test.txt")); //loads the text file Test.txt

public static function onLoaded(e:Event):void 
{
    var myArrayOfLines:Array = e.target.data.split(/\n/); //splits it up every new line
    trace(myArrayOfLines); //trace the text in Test.txt
    //Test.txt contains the word "Test"
}



public function foo()
{
    //how do i access myArrayOfLines? Example below
    //Name.text = ""+myArrayOfLines; DOES NOT WORK
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the variable outside of the onLoaded function. Then it can be accessed elsewhere:

```
var myArrayOfLines:Array;

public function onLoaded(e:Event):void 
{
    myArrayOfLines = e.target.data.split(/\n/); //splits it up every new line
    //...etc
}

public function foo()
{
    //display first item in array
    Name.text = ""+myArrayOfLines[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lee. Unfortunately doing myArrayOfLines = e.target.dara.split(/\n/); gives me an error "Access of undefined property of myArrayOfLines"

Comment: think ive spotted an error; you set onLoaded as a static function - which it probably doesnt need to be (edited my answer to reflect that). If you DO need it to be static, then add "static" before "var myArrayOfLines:Array"

Comment: Thanks! It's somewhat working now. It sets Name.text to "null" (rather than setting it to "Test.") It all compiles but I get this error http://pastebin.com/rRriH04p

Comment: "Property dara not found on flash.net.URLLoader" - looks like you have a spelling mistake: im guessing you have "e.target.dara" in your code? should be "e.target.data"